# How to save/zip binary/octet-stream s3 content to zip

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to add s3 bucket files into a zip. The files in the s3 bucket are in binary/octet-stream format.

When I run the below method

```
 public static void addFileToZip(ZipOutputStream zip, String fileName, InputStream fileContent) throws IOException {
    try {
      zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
      IOUtils.copy(fileContent, zip);
      zip.closeEntry();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      fileContent.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The IO Exception below is thrown when executing **IOUtils.copy** method

"exception": "Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 206,034; received: 0)"

Any suggestions on how I can handle this or what am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Edit:-
@LeeGreiner I am getting the InputStream like this:

```
public ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> getObject(String key) {
    try (S3Client s3 = s3Client.getClient()) {
      return s3.getObject(
          GetObjectRequest.builder()
              .bucket(bucketName)
              .key(key)
              .build()
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show how you are passing the InputStream to this method? Are you using `S3Object.getObjectContent()` and is the object the bucket or a file in the bucket?

Comment: @LeeGreiner I have added as edit in the question and it is file in the bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ResponseTransformer`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/sync/ResponseTransformer.html) to convert the response to an input stream:

```java
s3.getObject(getObjectRequest, ResponseTransformer.toInputStream());
```

My specific method is as follows (it assumes the `s3` connection has already been created):

```java
public static InputStream getObject(String key) throws IOException {

    GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(key)
            .build();

    return s3.getObject(getObjectRequest, ResponseTransformer.toInputStream());
}
```

The resulting input stream can then be added to your zip file in the usual way.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew! This has resolved my issue. 
Quick question, I noticed that when I remove the try-with-resources statement to get the S3client, my method works as well. Could you by any chance be knowing why that is so? Thank you.

Comment: I assume your try-with-resource code will automatically close the s3 client at the end of each `getObject()` method call. My sample code is actually poor in that regard - I removed that code for clarity. I think the best approach is the one outlined in the [client lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/creating-clients.html#client-lifecycle) documentation: treat the client as a long-lived object and explicitly call `s3.close()` when you no longer need it. With your approach, you are repeatedly opening it and closing it - probably unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It makes sense.